# Getting error "passing argument 2 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast" comparing two strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, matrix, gcc-warning

Im a student, and im trying to complete this program, which his objective is:

**Print the data of the product that has the same name as the requested name in input**

Everytime, when i try to compile the program, this warning appears:

`warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 100
#define M 8

int main (void) {
    int n;
    char name[N][M];
    char code[N][M];
    int price[N];
    char searchname;
    int i;
    int selection;
    int search, x;


    do {
        printf("Insert how many products to register: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    } while(n > N);

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Insert the name of the product n%d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", name[i]);

        printf("Insert the code of the product registered: ");
        scanf("%s", code[i]);

        printf("Insert the price of the product registered: ");
        scanf("%d", &price[i]);
    }

    do {
        printf("Choose one of the following options:\n\n");
        printf("1) Print name and price of the searched product (code)\n");
        printf("2) Print the product that has the same name as the name inserted\n");
        printf("0) Close the program\n\n");
        printf("Type the number of the option: ");
        scanf("%d", &selection);

        switch(selezione) {
            case 1:
                x = 0;

                printf("Insert the code of the product: ");
                scanf("%d", &search);

                for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    if(code[i] == search) {
                        printf("name: %s | price: %d\n\n", name[i], price[i]);

                        x = 1;
                    }
                }

                if(x == 0) {
                    printf("The searched code doesnt exist\n\n");
                }

            break;
            case 2:
                x = 0;

                printf("Insert the name to search: ");
                scanf("%s", searchname);

                for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    while(strcmp(name[i], searchname) == 0) {
                        printf("Product number %d | Code: %s | Price: %d\n\n", i + 1, code[i], price[i]);
                        x++;
                    }
                }

                if(x == 0) {
                    printf("There are no products with this name\n\n");
                }

            break;
            case 0:
            break;
            default:
                printf("This option doesnt exist");
            break;
        }
    } while(selection!= 0);

    return 0;
}
```

I searched around stack overflow for a while, and the posts that mention this problem weren't helpful.
What im trying to do, is compare the string `name[i]` with `searchname` which is a string too.
Am i missing something here?

Comment: `char searchname;` - doesn't look like string.

Comment: @EugeneSh. How do i initialize the string then? The program asked to the user `scanf("%s", searchname);`

Comment: A string is an array of `char`

Comment: Aside: that loop `while(strcmp(name[i], searchname) == 0)` is infinite, because none of the three variables change within the loop. Perhaps a simple `if` was intended.

Comment: @WeatherVane weird, even with a simple `if` i get an error. Also, how is that infinite, if i put a `for` loop?

Comment: Yes, because there remains the `searchname` error as previously commented. It is infinite loop because the three variables, `name` and `i` and `searchname` remain the same. They are not changed within the `while` loop. So once the `while` loop is entered, it is never left.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes, understood. But a string is an array or a matrix, defined as char. But why do i have to add seomthing else, when my `searchname` string is a single word that i have to search?

Comment: No, a string is an *array* of char terminated with a `'\0'`. You have a single char, which is not a string.

Comment: @WeatherVane so do i have to add `i++` in the while loop without the `for` loop?

Comment: No, you have to change `while` to `if` because you want to report and count each match *once*. The `i` is controlled by the outer `for` loop.

Comment: @WeatherVane even with an `if` it still shows the same error...

Comment: Yes, because there remains the `searchname` error as previously commented.

Comment: @WeatherVane so do i have to make `searchname` a matrix, like with `name`?

Comment: If this was more than just a typo, you should refer to your books on C.

Comment: @WeatherVane how do i fix the searchname error? I really dont know how to act in a case  like this.

Comment: You could try `char searchname[100];` You didn't write this code, did you?

Comment: The above comments have told you why you are getting the searchname error, and have told you how to fix it. It is up to you to apply this knowledge, and if you are still unable to fix the error, then come back and ask a question that has been informed by your attempts at applying this information.

Comment: @WeatherVane already tried, still getting the same error. I tried to play around with the string but i still get errors.

Comment: @TomDrake even with these kind of suggestion i cant still fix the error. As my knowledge, i looked around internet, sites, school documents and more, and i still cant resolve the issue.

Comment: @WeatherVane also yes i wrote this code

Comment: @WeatherVane points out that you could try redefining `searchname` as follows `char searchname[100];` Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What im trying to do, is compare the string `name[i]` with `searchname` which is a string too.

`char searchname;` - doesn't look like string.
                    – Eugene Sh.

You could try `char searchname[100];` …
                    – Weather Vane

Comment: Now, looking at the suggestion like this, i've understand the problem. I was confused and i tried to make every `searchname` as an array, in the `scanf` and in the loop. Also, looking back at the comments, i was totally wrong when using a `while` loop. In the end, i used `char searchname[M];` only in the variables, and using an `if` loop as Weather Vane told me.